# .app bundle displaying low resolution Tkinter window

Tags: macos, mac, applications, python

I asked this question already on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40484659/pyinstaller-tkinter-window-low-resolution-in-app-bundle-but-not-in-app-program) but since I didn't got yet an answer and this may be Mac specific I'm asking here again:

I'm using [Pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org) to package a Python app into a Mac App. This is working fine. Recently I have added a GUI window using Tkinter to check for updates, start/stop the app, etc.

There's something strange happening which I don't understand. After running successfully PyInstaller and creating a `onefile` standing app I get the following outcome after running `ls -al`:

```
-rwxr-xr-x   1 karold  staff  62756614  8 lis 11:08 mac
drwxr-xr-x   3 karold  staff       102  8 lis 11:09 mac.app
```

Here's the outcome while running the `mac` file (upper image) and the `mac.app` (lower image): 
[image]

Notice the difference in the window resolution, although the `mac.app` package contains exactly the same `mac` program ...

Is there something I'm missing to get the same solution in both cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer by carefully reading [the docs](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#spec-file-options-for-a-mac-os-x-bundle).

I was missing High Resolution retina settings in the app part of my spec file, as mentioned in the above mentioned docs:

*For example, when you use PyQt5, you can set NSHighResolutionCapable to True to let your app also work in retina screen*

Once I added the `info_plist` parameter as provided below the problem was gone:)

```
app = BUNDLE(exe,
     name='myscript.app',
     icon=None,
     bundle_identifier=None
     info_plist={
        'NSHighResolutionCapable': 'True'
        },
     )
```